# Where can I get/need help creating an in-memory InstanceStore

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I've been doing lots of work recently on the new Workflow 4.0.  One of the things that would make it easier to whip together test apps would be an in memory [InstanceStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.persistence.instancestore(VS.100).aspx).  One that holds  offloaded workflows in memory for a short while.

The documentation on how to create a store is pretty anemic, and the interface on it is pretty complex and obscure.  Instead of investing a day figuring it out, I'm wondering if anybody knows of either a good explanation of how to implement an InstanceStore, or just some code that does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the 2 things you really need to implement are these virtual protected members:

object OnCreateInstanceHandle(InstanceHandle);

and

void OnFreeInstanceHandle(InstanceHandle, object);

Edit: WRONG see below

Comment: I could tell you about that much.  I'm looking for details on how to accomplish this, as I don't recognize a pattern here and the documentation is a bit lacking in details on how one of these things work.

Comment: Update, I investigated this more and it seems like I was totally wrong about this. The *real* thing you need to do seems to be writing a command handler, probably overriding ExecuteCommand(), which handles the different subclasses of System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceCommand, such as LoadWorkflowByInstanceKeyCommand

Comment: I'm accepting because I believe your last comment is correct (the whole "ExecuteCommand" pattern is a bit bizarre to me but it appears to be how it works) and I don't think there are any ready-made solutions out there.  Thanks.

Comment: I just found out recently that there is also a XmlPersistantStore sample in the official WF samples. Path:

WF\Application\PurchaseProcess\CodedWorkflow\CS\WfDefinition\XmlWorkflowInstanceStore.cs